# CAN protocol : How to start with CAN interface with Microcontroller

Tags: pic, microchip, can, vfd

I want to communicate with VFD (variable frequency drive) via CAN open protocol.

I have never used CAN before. So can anyone Guide me from where Should I start with ? Any link or Suggestions would really of great help.

I would be using **dsPic/pic24** microcontroller. So, is there pre-written libraries that can make my design bit easier.

Also any suggestion for choosing a right controller ??

I am just looking for a right direction to avoid wasting time, as reading too many tutorial is also dangerous.

thanks

Comment: http://www.kvaser.com/software/7330130980914/V1/can2spec.pdf

Comment: Pic a mcu and then read the datasheet to see if it has the required interface (UART ?) and then look for the development kits to see if they have a complete example. Microchip.com probably does evaluation boards with CAN built in and the demo libraries

Comment: @Spoon The required interface for CAN is... CAN.

Comment: Our purpose here, is not to save you from doing all of the work you should be doing yourself. *You* do the research - you'll learn far more that way.

Comment: 20 years ago I looked at CAN and it looked hard... Today I would look at eval boards or dev kits to get up and running quickly with the mcu family I want to use. Some have CAN interfaces built in.  That will be the quickest solution. For the cheapest to build solution you might bit bang the whole interface from the ground up... that's not my choice in most cases.

Comment: Thanks every one for your suggestions. I will start with some evaluation board to understand the protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, CAN is the hardware layers and CANopen is a protocol running on top of that. You will need to know how both CAN and CANopen work in detail.

Then pick a MCU which has a built-in CAN controller. This will save you lots of time and costs: avoid using external CAN controllers.

Then you have to figure out what kind of CANopen implementation the device uses. CANopen has a number of sub-standards for various applications, known as "device profiles". The device could be using one of the standardized device profiles or it could be using a custom one.

Depending on your requirements and what else is there on the bus, you might be able to get away with sending/receiving the known, hard-coded messages needed. If you want your MCU to act as a full-blown, standard-compliant CANopen device, then that's no trivial task. The sane solution then is to get yourself a pre-made CANopen protocol stack, either a commercial one or perhaps the free [CANFestival](http://www.canfestival.org/).

Note that even if you find a stack with a port to your specific MCU, implementing it to get along with the rest of your application is usually not a trivial task. If you know nothing of CAN at all, and this is a one man show, prepare for a long project that might take you at least one year, probably longer than that.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I will start with Evaluation board Explorer 16  with dsPic33f. This is one man show but will try to find some better way to get the things done on time. :)